# How to listen to requests on all adresses with TCPServer

Tags: ruby, tcpserver

I want to create a simple webserver to communicate with my running Ruby script via a web browser.

I can only set the TCPServer's address to one address per time. For example, if I don't set any address at all, I can only access it on the computer it is running on with 'localhost:port'. If I set it to the computer's network address I can access it from the whole network via its address but I can't access it via 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1'. However, in the end the server should be accessable from all over the world by just having it's IP.

Here is the basic source code of the server:

```
server = TCPServer.open("some.ip.v4.address", 8080)

loop do

  Thread.start(server.accept) do |socket|

    #Do something...

  end
end
```

Is something like that possible? How would I do it?

Comment: Shot in the dark but try `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: Okay so with 0.0.0.0 it works that I can access it with both localhost/127.0.0.1 as well as with the local network ip address. However, I can't access it from an external source. I tried using the ip address that shows up if I visit sites like whatismyipaddress.com but it doesn't work. The ports are opened.

Sorry if this is a dumb question but this is the first time I program a server.

Comment: Your question could possibly do better on [su]. But, TCPServer is for creating new TCP-based services. You're creating a service that uses HTTPd, since you're talking to a browser. I'd recommend researching how to do this using Sinatra or Rack. You might also want to look into Passenger and even nginx if you need more options.

Comment: Define "external". It's often the case that you'll be behind a layer of NAT and using a private IP that is not directly accessible from the general internet. If you want to open something up you need to use [UPnP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play), for which there are several Rubygems solutions that might work for you. Experiment and see what's best.